# Where are the stacks for the other threads located in a process virtual address space?

Tags: linux, assembly, x86, stack-memory, virtual-address-space

The following image shows where the sections of a process are laid out in the process's virtual address space (in Linux):

[image]

You can see that there is only one stack section (since this process only has one thread I assume).

But what if this process has another thread, where will the stack for this second thread be located? will it be located immediately below the first stack?

Comment: C tag is not relevant, C doesn't define their concepts.

Comment: Also see [The Stack Clash](https://blog.qualys.com/securitylabs/2017/06/19/the-stack-clash). Qualys managed to break the separation between logical memory regions. They could use the one memory region to overwrite objects in another region. Linux was especially vulnerable (except systems running with [gresecurity patches](https://www.grsecurity.net/)). Also see [More CONFIG_VMAP_STACK vulnerabilities](http://www.openwall.com/lists/oss-security/2017/06/24/1) on the OSS-Security mailing list.

Answer (score 23):

Stack space for a new thread is created by the parent thread with [`mmap(MAP_ANONYMOUS|MAP_STACK)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html).  So they're in the "memory map segment", as your diagram labels it.  It can end up anywhere that a large `malloc()` could go.  (glibc `malloc(3)` uses `mmap(MAP_ANONYMOUS)` for large allocations.)

(`MAP_STACK` is currently a no-op, and exists in case some future architecture needs special handling).

You pass a pointer to the new thread's stack space to [the `clone(2)` system call](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/clone.2.html) which actually creates the thread.  (Try using `strace -f` on a multi-threaded process sometime).  See also [this blog post about creating a thread using raw Linux syscalls](http://nullprogram.com/blog/2015/05/15/).

See [this answer on a related question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5369022/224132) for some more details about mmaping stacks.  e.g. `MAP_GROWSDOWN` doesn't prevent another `mmap()` from picking the address right below the thread stack, so you can't depend on it to dynamically grow a small stack the way you can for the main thread's stack (where the kernel reserves the address space even though it's not mapped yet).

So even though `mmap(MAP_GROWSDOWN)` was designed for allocating stacks, [it's so bad that Ulrich Drepper proposed removing it in 2.6.29](https://lwn.net/Articles/294001/).

---

Also, note that your memory-map diagram is for a 32-bit kernel.  A 64-bit kernel doesn't have to reserve any user virtual-address space for mapping kernel memory, so a 32-bit process running on an amd64 kernel can use the full 4GB of virtual address space.  (Except for the low 64k by default (sysctl `vm.mmap_min_addr = 65536`), so NULL-pointer dereference does actually fault.  And [the top page is also reserved as error codes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47712502/why-cant-i-mmapmap-fixed-the-highest-virtual-page-in-a-32-bit-linux-process-o), not valid pointers.)

---

Related:

See [Relation between stack limit and threads](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4369078/relation-between-stack-limit-and-threads) for more about stack-size for pthreads.  `getrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK)` is the main thread's stack size.  Linux pthreads uses `RLIMIT_STACK` as the stack size for new threads, too.

Comment: "64-bit kernel doesn't have to reserve any user virtual-address space for mapping kernel memory" — wait, really? How would that work? I've tried to do something like this but failed because IIRC addresses in the IDTR/GDTR are linear, not physical so they just had to be mapped in the user-space.

Comment: @Joker_vD: Right, but they're mapped outside the low 4GiB that 32-bit user-space can access.   The [Q&A linked in that paragraph](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47712502/why-cant-i-mmapmap-fixed-the-highest-virtual-page-in-a-32-bit-linux-process-o) shows Linux `/proc/<PID>/maps` output for 32-bit user-space under a 64-bit kernel with the stack at `fffdd000-ffffe000`.   A 64-bit user-space process does only get the low half of canonical addresses, with the kernel reserving the high half like you were thinking of.