# Threads have the same virtual memory space, but different stacks? Where are the stacks?

Tags: multithreading, language-agnostic, virtual-memory, callstack, memory-layout

A program's runtime stack is stored as part of virtual memory, and starts at address X on system Y (not taking into account randomization). When a new thread is created, with its own independent stack, where is it stored? (threads share their virtual memory)

Comment: Please edit your question. It does not specify the context, so it is impossible to provide the answer. For example, add "64-bit Microsoft Windows process", if this is the case.

Comment: As a generic answer, the stack for a new thread can potentially be placed pretty much anywhere in the process address space, and that’d be decided by the library/software providing the thread implementation (most likely in cooperation with the operating system). For Linux/pthreads, answers to the following question contain many more details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44858528.

Answer (score 0):

[Almost](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-createthread) [every](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/beginthread-beginthreadex?view=vs-2019) [threading](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_attr_setstacksize.3.html) [libraries](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#Thread%28java.lang.ThreadGroup,%20java.lang.Runnable,%20java.lang.String,%20long%29) lets you specify the stack size:

```c
HANDLE CreateThread(
  LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES   lpThreadAttributes,
  SIZE_T                  dwStackSize,
  LPTHREAD_START_ROUTINE  lpStartAddress,
  __drv_aliasesMem LPVOID lpParameter,
  DWORD                   dwCreationFlags,
  LPDWORD                 lpThreadId
);
```

```cpp
uintptr_t _beginthread( // NATIVE CODE
   void( __cdecl *start_address )( void * ),
   unsigned stack_size,
   void *arglist
);
```

```c
int pthread_attr_setstacksize(pthread_attr_t *attr, size_t stacksize);
```

```java
Thread(ThreadGroup group, Runnable target, String name, long stackSize)
```

Before the thread starts, the operating system allocates memory (just like `malloc`) for the new thread to execute. Some systems also provide gaps ("guard pages") so that the stacks won't collide with each other. Where they are stored are platform-dependent, but generally subsequent threads' stacks may be allocated in a different region than the main thread. For Linux this is handled by the C library and uses plain `mmap` to allocate them AFAIK.